# opencensus, golang, metrics: Не могу найти ошибку в метриках. Может кто помочь?

Tags: golang, prometheus

Есть код:
[image: metrics.go]

[image: main.go]

**Когда его запускаю, то получаю следующий результат:**

[image: result]

**Мне кажется или так не должно быть?) По моим ощущениям, если мне приходит 1, то в в ведре с "1" будет +1, все остальные не должны изменяться. Я прав? Может мне кто нибудь объяснить? Поправить меня?**

Comment: Вы тут уже 2 года, а так и не научились, правильно задавать вопросы. Ужас. Вам суда [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: последний раз вопрос задавал 2 года назад. Ужас ужас ужас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был на поверхности. 
Aggregation: view.Distribution - собирает метрики для "Гистограммы". 
В связи с этим и получаются такие данные...